# How can I decrypt TLS packets of other devices (Wifi Hotspot) from Windows?

Tags: ssl, encryption, wireshark, tls1.2

I am using WireShark to monitor my network. I connect my phone to Windows HotSpot and I can monitor network of my phone too. For TLS decrypting, I applied steps in the link below:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#Using_the_.28Pre.29-Master-Secret

SSL info of the browsers are written my SSLKEYLOGFILE but SSL info of my phone doesn't. I easily decrypt browser packets but phone requests are still encrypted. How can I get SSL info of my phone packets? Is there any way to write SSL info of HotSpot connection to SSLKEYLOGFILE or is there any other solution?

Edit: I am very very newbie for encryption and networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please setup your Android device to use "Fiddler" tool as a proxy. Then you can use fiddler tool for debugging on Windows. You just need to install fiddler root certificate. Refer below link:

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-android-traffic-with-fiddler

And to capture iOS Traffic with Fiddler:
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-ios-traffic-with-fiddler